# Flutter children containers max width

Tags: flutter, constraints

I'm new to flutter and am struggling trying to get my containers contained with a max width.
I've tried using all sorts of ways answered on here but for some reason the containers just ignore the constraints.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: ctrl,
              children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like my containers to look like this when I widen my browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FcDe.png)

But instead it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgJjY.png)

If someone could help me figure out why my containers keep ignoring my constraints that would help me allot

Thank you!

Error after adding     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTtOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

use property of width in container put the below code it'll be work for you.

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:15,right:15),child:Container(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,child:YourChild()))

Answer (score 0):

Add width to your container and comment margin from it. Margin is taking spacing all side.

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

// margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
```

Comment: I got an Error. I updated the question with the picture of the error

Comment: In order to use MediaQuery,  you need to create a Stateful Widget.

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

Create you page-  MyPage()

By removing margin you can access full page width and height.

Comment: So I implemented that and my container disappears off the screen